# Set up .bash_profile and .bashrc for local and remote access

Tags: ssh, bashrc, bash-profile

I've noticed that when I open a terminal on my ubuntu machine locally, it sources `.bashrc`, but when I connect via ssh, it sources `.bash_profile`. I added a line in `.bashrc` to source `.bash_profile` so I have both files sources when working locally. I'd like to have the same behavior when accessing the machine remotely. Of course, if I just source `.bashrc` in `.bash_profile` I'll have an infinite loop. What's the proper way to set this up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use command `shopt login_shell`. If the shell is a non login-shell then it will print `login_shell off`, and if it is a login-shell then it will print `login_shell on`.

`.bash_profile` is sourced by bash whenever it is started in interactive login mode or accessed via ssh. So you can put an if condition in `.bash_profile` like :

```
if [ "$(shopt login_shell | cut -f2)" = "on" ]
 then
  source .bashrc
fi
```

`.bashrc` is sourced whenever bash is started in terminal, so you can put an if condition in `.bashrc`

```
if [ "$(shopt login_shell | cut -f2)" = "off" ]
then
 source .bash_profile
fi
```